# WSO2 API HTTP POST endpoint request payload getting passed to backend endpoint with some extra characters preceding and succeeding the actual payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager, the published API has a POST endpoint. On calling this POST endpoint, the payload body is getting passed to backend Endpoint with some extra characters preceding and succeeding the actual payload.

for example if i directly make a POST request to the backend endpoint without involving API manager, the payload received at the backend is

{"uname":"dlc"}

if i make a POST request to the API Manager, which in turn proxies it to the backend endpoint, in this case the payload received at the backend is

f
{"uname":"dlc"}
0

Any clue?

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as any error you see in server logs, what is the rest client you are using, etc.?

Comment: There are no errors in  the server logs. When the request comes through WSO2 API manager at the backend and then if i try to stream/extract the payload from the request, the request payload is null. Whereas, if i make a direct POST request to backend with a payload using REST client or python request module, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is actually happening to the request by enabling wirelogs. (see whether request payload is going out from API manager, what comes in to API manager, etc.)  See [how to enable wire logs](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html) and check what is actually happening and you would be able to figure out the issue.

**UPDATE**

seems like your backend application cannot handle chunked messages. You can disable chunking from api manager by following this http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-chunking-wso2-esb-proxy.html . This describes how to disable chunking from WSO2 ESB. but you can do the same for API manager rest api as well. (using  [custom mediator extension](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions))

Comment: Hi, Thanks for directing towards wirelog. In the wire debug. i can actually see that payload is getting passed to the backend endpoint. But when i try to stream/extract the payload from the request at the backend, the request payload is null. Whereas, if i make a direct POST request to backend with a payload using REST client or python request module it works fine.

Comment: You can use tcp monitor (or similar tool) to capture request going to the backend on both occasions (AM -> backend and Restclient -> backend) and compare the two requests (all the headers and payload). Then you could find what is missing from the request sent from api manager.

Comment: i have compared the two requests using wireshark. and there is a difference in the payload that is getting received at backend. From Restclient the payload is --> {"uname":"dlc"} and when it comes through WSO2-AM the payload received is --> f {"uname":"dlc"} 0. Does WSO2-AM is adding something to the payload?

Comment: backend is getting message as chunked message. Either write backend to handle this chunked message or disable chunking from api manager. see http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-chunking-wso2-esb-proxy.html . this shows for ESB but same thing can be done for api

Comment: I tried adding these two properties in the <insequence> section                            <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />     in the file /wso2am-1.10.0/repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml . But it didn't work out. Is this it the right place i am making the change?

Comment: no. add it as a property in the in sequence in the api as a custom sequnce. see the updated answer.  Or you can manually add it to the api synapse config file (in /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api location). this is not the recommended way. recommended way is using custom mediation sequence.